Get List of Collection REST API - Azure DevOps Server (TFS)
I am trying to get list of collection in from Azure DevOps Server. There is no API available to fetch the list of collections.
[tfs url]/_apis/projectCollections?$top=1000

I tried above API (PAT authorization)

To get all the collections which your account has access to, you can try the steps below.

Create a PAT for all accessible organizations


Run the following PowerShell scripts.


$token = "{PAT}"
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
$url="{Server URL}/_apis/projectCollections?%24top=1000?api-version=7.1-preview.2"
$head = @{ Authorization =" Basic $token" }
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method GET -Headers $head
$result| ConvertTo-Json


PAT: You create in step 1.

Server URL: Copy the part of your collection URL before the collection name. Taking the following screenshot as an example, it should be http://wi***


Result:




It's probably worth noting that this API is undocumented as of this date, and it might only apply to servers/services that support API version 7.1 Preview 2 or later (Azure DevOps Services, and Azure DevOps Server 2022.2 or later)
